# How to convert generator type to string?

Tags: python, python-2.7, for-loop, generator, yield

I have a simple for loop:

```
def my_function(myList):
    for x in myList:
        yield x

y = my_function(my_list)
```

and `x` is used as input for the function below:

```
def my_second_function(y):
    print(y.rfind("name")
```

But I've got the error:

```
AttributeError: 'generator' object has no attribute 'rfind'.
```

Comment: What do you mean by "convert?"  What exactly are you trying to do?  A generator function is meant to be used like `list(yourFunc())` or `for val in yourFunc():`.

Comment: What is the type of elements in my_list? Did you mean that loop inside a generator function?

Comment: my_list contains strings and those strings I want to pass to other function as input and use some string methods on them.

Answer (score 2):

`x` is not a generator, rather the *function* yielding from your for loop is a generator!

```py
>>> def my_function():
...     for x in my_list:
...         yield x
...
>>> type(my_function)
<class 'function'>
>>> type(my_function())
<class 'generator'>
```

```py
>>> my_list = [1,2,3]
>>> next(my_function())
1
```

In order to make the result a string, you may simply want to call `str()` on `x` before or after it comes out of the generator!

If you want the contents of the entire generator all together, you need to pop it all (rather than just the first or N values), perhaps iterating over it with the string method `.join()`

All together

```py
>>> ",".join(str(a) for a in my_function())
'1,2,3'
```

(NOTE that `.join()` is actually method of `","` here)

Comment: my_list contains strings and those strings I want to pass to other function as input and use some string methods on them.

Comment: you may simply want to iterate over your generator then (the function which `yield`s in it)

Comment: I will be grateful for example :)

Comment: you'll have to add more to your question! as-written, it's too open-ended to help more!

Comment: Hope now is better :)

Comment: ah, you want to iterate over (`for member in y:...`) or call `next()` on `y`